# I cannot resolve a conflict between jquery and prototyp.js

Tags: jquery, tabs, prototypejs, lightbox, conflict

It is with a heavy heart and thick head that I request help. I am designing a site for a care home (here - http://www.coolpenguin.co.uk/yourhealth/yourhealth-cedarcourt.php)

The site uses jquery for the tabs and prototype.js for the lightbox feature (show on the second tab called life here).

The site is brand new, so I accept that formatting etc is incomplete but I have ground to a halt with this issue. I can either have working tabs or a working lightbox gallery not both.

I have tried  jQuery.noConflict(); in numerous ways, even changing the $ sign in all of the associated js files for lightbox and vice versa in the header for the tabs.

I need to have an image gallery that works on the tabs. I can't be the first to require these two features, but over three hours on this problem and I cannot solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get the question, noConflict is pretty simple

```
var $s = jQuery.noConflict();
```

then use jQuery like so ...

```
$s(document).ready(function() {
```

Also, your jquery version pretty old.

Comment: The question is, lightbox and my tabs conflict only one or the other works. It is caused by a jquery / prototype conflict. I will try your suggestion, and I am very grateful for the response.

Comment: Awesome, I think it was my fault, I didn't see one of the $ signs! But your solution worked, very very grateful.